# PHP equivalent for UnderscoreJS each

Tags: php, collections

Is there a built in each method - similar to that of UnderscoreJS- in php  that applies a callback for every entry in the array passing in the current $value, $key, $collection with the ability to mutate $value if needed.

Here is a custom implementation.

```
  function _each(array $collection, $callback) {
        foreach ($collection as $key => &$value) {
            $callback($value, $key, $collection);
        }
        return $collection;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php).  The array will be passed by reference and not returned:

```
array_walk($collection, 'something', $collection);
```

To modify the value the callback will need to accept it as a reference:

```
function something(&$value, $key, $userdata) {
    // do stuff
}
```

There is also an [array_walk_recursive()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) if needed.

Answer (score 0):

`array_map` might be what you are looking for in this case

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: Will not _mutate $value if needed_.

Comment: what do you mean by mutate? do you mean modify?

Comment: That's from the OP and I took it to mean modify.